# Coding in Python: Combining List Data

Tags: python, list, file

I need to write a tabular file that has the lists written so that it would come up as "Bob, 50, 45, 39", "Haley, 28, 27, 45", etc for the rest of the names, showing a report of their grades. So far, I know how to separate the names or numbers from one list, but I do not know how to combine the data.

```
students = ["Bob", "Haley", "Chris", "Nolan", "Asuka", "Cameron", "Tommy"]

midterm = [50, 28, 49, 90, 74, 0, 47]

essay = [45, 27, 76, 94, 0, 73, 67]

final = [39, 45, 65, 74, 36, 29, 90]

f = open ("student_data.txt", "w")

for i in students:
    f.write(str(i) + "\n")
f.close ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
for i in range(len(students)):
  f.write(students[i] + str(midterm[i]) .... and so on)
  f.flush()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is help you. just change `print` to `write`.

```
students = ["Bob", "Haley", "Chris", "Nolan", "Asuka", "Cameron", "Tommy"]
midterm = [50, 28, 49, 90, 74, 0, 47]
essay = [45, 27, 76, 94, 0, 73, 67]
final = [39, 45, 65, 74, 36, 29, 90]

z = zip(students,midterm,essay,final)

with open("student_data.txt", "w") as f :
      f.write("\n".join(",".join(map(str,x)) for x in z))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must write a tabular file you may as well leverage the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module:

```
f = csv.writer(open("student_data.txt", "w", newlines=""))
f.writerows(zip(students, midterm, essay, final))
```